# How to load several FXML in one class?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

I create **several component** with SceneBuilder, my goal is now to use all this files for creating a **complete window**. But I can't load several FXML, *here's what I try to do* :

```
    private MenuBar menuBar;
    private Pane filtersView;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

    loader.setLocation(MainWindow.class.getResource("../component/menuBar/MenuBar.fxml"));
    menuBar = (MenuBar) loader.load();

    loader.setLocation(MainWindow.class.getResource("../component/filtersView/FiltersView.fxml"));
    filtersView = (Pane) loader.load();
```

Here's the *returning error* :

> Root value already specified.

Should I have to **create a loader for each component** ?

Comment: Yes. Create a new loader each time.

Comment: Could you answer and tell me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `FXMLLoader` instance has a number of interdependent properties (such as the `root` and `controller`) which are set either by parsing the FXML file, or programmatically. Each of these also interacts in various ways with the `namespace` map held by the `FXMLLoader` instance.

Because the life-cycle of the `FXMLLoader` would be highly complex if it could be reused, it is an error to set either the `root` or the `controller` more than once. (What should happen to the `controller` if the `root` were set to a new value? What about the properties in the `namespace`?).

Consequently, you should only use an `FXMLLoader` instance once. Create a new loader for each FXML file you want to load:

```
FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader();

menuLoader.setLocation(MainWindow.class.getResource("../component/menuBar/MenuBar.fxml"));
menuBar = (MenuBar) menuLoader.load();

FXMLLoader filtersLoader = new FXMLLoader();
filtersLoader.setLocation(MainWindow.class.getResource("../component/filtersView/FiltersView.fxml"));
filtersView = (Pane) filtersLoader.load();
```

Comment: Documentation for the `FXMLLoader` is basically non-existent, by the way.